# How do Javascript getters work?

Tags: javascript, oop

i'v been using javascript getters for a long time in my applications, and always thought

that they work like this:

```
myobject.prototype.__defineGetter__('something', function () {
   return DoSomeHeavyComputation() // this will be executed only once and will be saved
})

new myobject()
myobject.something // the computation will be done here
myobject.something // no computation will be done here.
```

i just found out the computation is done each time...

is there a resource or something that shows how do they actually work ?

Comment: It's just a function, lifer any other. You *could* cache the value, for example by executing a function that returns a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article is awesome and gets really into the nitty-gritty of prototyping and object instantiation: http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-7-2-oop-ecmascript-implementation/

Answer (score 1):

If you define a getter on a property of an object it will be called each time you try to access that property.

```
obj.prop;
```

If you want to cache the result you should do it manually.

Similary if you define a setter on a property of an object it will be called each time you set the property.

```
obj.prop = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like memoization.

http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#memoize